# How can i perform some actions after the program ends?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. How can i perform some actions after the program ends? I tried to use ROSInterruptException but it did not work.

```
!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def talker():

    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        hello_str = "hello world %s" % rospy.get_time()
        rospy.loginfo(hello_str)
        pub.publish(hello_str)
        rate.sleep()

try:
    talker()
except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    rospy.loginfo("TEST")
```

And when I do Ctrl+C the "TEST" line does not appear. What have I done wrong? Why the exception does not work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309529/how-can-i-perform-some-actions-after-the-program-ends?/) by [kolyazoloto](https://answers.ros.org/users/38735/kolyazoloto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can register a callback for the shutdown hook in rospy as [described here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Registering_shutdown_hooks).

This shutdown even is called before the ros system closes so you should still be able to write log messages. Your code will look something like this:

```
!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def talker():

    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        hello_str = "hello world %s" % rospy.get_time()
        rospy.loginfo(hello_str)
        pub.publish(hello_str)
        rate.sleep()

def my_shutdown_handler():
  print "shutdown time!"
  rospy.loginfo("test shutdown.")

try:
    rospy.on_shutdown(my_shutdown_handler)
    talker()
except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    pass
```

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kolyazoloto](https://answers.ros.org/users/38735/kolyazoloto/) on 2018-11-28**:
Thank you.